# Create a binary indicator matrix (Boolean matrix) in R

Tags: r, matrix, dummy-data

I have a list of data indicating attendance to conferences like this:

```
Event                     Participant  
ConferenceA               John   
ConferenceA               Joe  
ConferenceA               Mary    
ConferenceB               John  
ConferenceB               Ted  
ConferenceC               Jessica
```

I would like to create a binary indicator attendance matrix of the following format:

```
Event        John  Joe  Mary  Ted  Jessica  
ConferenceA  1     1    1     0    0  
ConferenceB  1     0    0     1    0  
ConferenceC  0     0    0     0    1
```

Is there a way to do this in R?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reshaping a column from a data frame into several columns using R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030283/reshaping-a-column-from-a-data-frame-into-several-columns-using-r) ... and searching on [r] create indicator matrix brought up several others that were relevant (with either `xtabs`, `table` or one of the 'reshape2' functions).

Comment: I initially voted to close but this example has a much better title and is much better visually to understand (original output and expected output are shown).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming your `data.frame` is called "mydf", simply use `table`:

```
> table(mydf)
             Participant
Event         Jessica Joe John Mary Ted
  ConferenceA       0   1    1    1   0
  ConferenceB       0   0    1    0   1
  ConferenceC       1   0    0    0   0
```

If there is a chance that someone would have attended a conference more than once, leading `table` to return a value greater than 1, you can simply recode all values greater than 1 to 1, like this.

```
temp <- table(mydf)
temp[temp > 1] <- 1
```

Note that this returns a `table`. If you want a `data.frame` to be returned, use `as.data.frame.matrix`:

```
> as.data.frame.matrix(table(mydf))
            Jessica Joe John Mary Ted
ConferenceA       0   1    1    1   0
ConferenceB       0   0    1    0   1
ConferenceC       1   0    0    0   0
```

---

In the above, "mydf" is defined as:

```
mydf <- structure(list(Event = c("ConferenceA", "ConferenceA", 
  "ConferenceA", "ConferenceB", "ConferenceB", "ConferenceC"), 
  Participant = c("John", "Joe", "Mary", "John", "Ted", "Jessica")), 
  .Names = c("Event", "Participant"), class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Please share your data in a similar manner in the future.

Comment: +1 for `as.data.frame.matrix` since `as.data.frame` would reverse the `table` operation.

Comment: @Ananda Awesome! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

@Ananda's answer is way better but I thought I'd throw up another approach using [qdap](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qdap/).  It only shines in the instance where "someone would have attended a conference more than once".

I included an instance when "someone would have attended a conference more than once" as pointed out by Ananda.  In this case using the `adjmat` function and pulling out the Boolean matrix could be helpful.

**Data With Double Attendee:**

```
## dat <- read.table(text="Event                     Participant  
## ConferenceA               John   
## ConferenceA               Joe  
## ConferenceA               Mary    
## ConferenceB               John  
## ConferenceB               Ted  
## ConferenceB               Ted
## ConferenceC               Jessica  ", header=TRUE)
```

**A table of counts:**

```
library(qdap)
wfm(dat[, 1], dat[, 2], lower.case = FALSE)

## > wfm(dat[, 1], dat[, 2], lower.case = FALSE)
##             Jessica Joe John Mary Ted
## conferenceA       0   1    1    1   0
## conferenceB       0   0    1    0   2
## conferenceC       1   0    0    0   0
```

**With mtabulate**

```
with(dat, mtabulate(split(Participant, Event)))

##             Jessica Joe John Mary Ted
## ConferenceA       0   1    1    1   0
## ConferenceB       0   0    1    0   2
## ConferenceC       1   0    0    0   0
```

**A Boolean matrix:**

```
adjmat(wfm(dat[, 1], dat[, 2], lower.case = FALSE))$boolean

## > adjmat(wfm(dat[, 1], dat[, 2], lower.case = FALSE))$boolean
##             Jessica Joe John Mary Ted
## conferenceA       0   1    1    1   0
## conferenceB       0   0    1    0   1
## conferenceC       1   0    0    0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

One more baseR way, using function `xtabs`

```
xtabs(~mydf$Event+mydf$Participant)

             mydf$Participant
mydf$Event    Jessica Joe John Mary Ted
  ConferenceA       0   1    1    1   0
  ConferenceB       0   0    1    0   1
  ConferenceC       1   0    0    0   0

#using data
mydf <- structure(list(Event = c("ConferenceA", "ConferenceA", 
                                 "ConferenceA", "ConferenceB", "ConferenceB", "ConferenceC"), 
                       Participant = c("John", "Joe", "Mary", "John", "Ted", "Jessica")), 
                  .Names = c("Event", "Participant"), class = "data.frame", 
                  row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```