# Are dataframe[ ,-1] and dataframe[-1] the same?

Tags: r, dataframe

Sorry this seems like a really silly question but are `dataframe[ ,-1]` and `dataframe[-1]` the same, and does it work for all data types?

And why are they the same

Comment: In addition to answers below, this topic is covered in Advanced R: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html, your answer is there as well.

Comment: Sorry for bad response - I was not thinking of a data.frame. Mea culpa

Comment: @CarlWitthoft we all forgive you! :-)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Almost.

`[-1]` uses the fact that a data.frame is a list, so when you do `dataframe[-1]` it returns another data.frame (list) without the first element (i.e. column).

`[ ,-1]`uses the fact that a data.frame is a two dimensional array, so when you do `dataframe[, -1]` you get the sub-array that does not include the first column.

A priori, they sound like the same, but the second case also tries by default to reduce the dimension of the subarray it returns. So depending on the dimensions of your `dataframe` you may get a data.frame or a vector, see for example:

```
> data <- data.frame(a = 1:2, b = 3:4)
> class(data[-1])
[1] "data.frame"
> class(data[, -1])
[1] "integer"
```

You can use `drop = FALSE` to override that behavior:

```
> class(data[, -1, drop = FALSE])
[1] "data.frame"
```

Comment: I was trying to put an example of a plot, but I'll just ask. Will a plot be affected by which you use. ie if you havent converted back into a dataframe

Comment: Unlikely, but you could show us how you use `plot` to confirm. Also give use `dim(dataframe)`.

Comment: Thanks everybody. @flodel, I'll carry on trying to solve my plot problem. Will post again if I can't get it to work.

Comment: One of the reasons Hadley created tibbles: no matter the dimensions, in either case, the result is a tibble.

Answer (score 3):

`dataframe[-1]` will treat your data in vector form, thus returning all but the very first element [[edit]] which as has been pointed out, turns out to be a column, as a `data.frame` is a `list`.  `dataframe[,-1]` will treat your data in matrix form, returning all but the first column.

Comment: You need to remove the "No." dataframe is a vector, but not an atomic vector. Its first element is the first column.

Comment: each list element of the data.frame is a column, I don't think he said anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, wanted to leave this as a comment but thought it was too big, I just found it interesting that the only one which remains a non integer is dataframe[1].

Further to Carl's answer, it seems dataframe[[1]] is treated as a matrix as well. 
But dataframe[1] isn't....

But it can't be treated as a matrix cause the results for dataframe[[1]] and matrix[[1]] are different.

```
D <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:16,4))
D
M <- (matrix(1:16,4))
M
> D[ ,1]        # data frame leaving out first column
[1] 1 2 3 4
> D[[1]]        # first column of dataframe
[1] 1 2 3 4
> D[1]          # First column of dataframe
  V1
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
> 
> class(D[ ,1])
[1] "integer"
> class(D[[1]])
[1] "integer"
> class(D[1])
[1] "data.frame"
> 
> M[ ,1]        # matrix leaving out first column
[1] 1 2 3 4
> M[[1]]        # First element of first row & col
[1] 1
> M[1]          # First element of first row & col
[1] 1
> 
> class(M[ ,1])
[1] "integer"
> class(M[[1]])
[1] "integer"
> class(M[1])
[1] "integer"
```