# Extracting columns from a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

What is the difference between the following two ways of extracting columns from a data frame?

```
df = data.frame(a=1:5, b=6:10, c=11:15)
cols = c("a","b")
df[, cols]  # Method A
df[cols]    # Method B
```

Most references that I've found use Method A. However, as far as I can tell, Method B works just as well.

EDIT:
I noticed a difference when `cols = c("a")`. Method A gives

```
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

whereas Method B gives the (expected?) result of

```
  a
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
```

Comment: Related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21137385/1201032