# Update some columns conditionally with max value for all values in chosen columns (data.table, r)

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset of the type 900,000 x 500, but the following shows a toy dataset apt for the question.

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- data.table(x = c(1,2,4,0), y = c(0,0,10,15), z = c(1,1,1,0))
```

I would like to do the following:

1. For columns y and z
2. select rows the value for which = 0
3. replace these with the max+1, where max is computed over the entire column

I am very new to data.table. Looking at examples of questions here at stackoverflow, I couldn't find a similar question, except this: 
[How to replace NA values in a table *for selected columns*? data.frame, data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379081/how-to-replace-na-values-in-a-table-for-selected-columns-data-frame-data-tab/19384699#19384699)

My own attempt is as follows, but this does not work:

```
for (col in c("x", "y")) df1[(get(col)) == 0, (col) := max(col) + 1)
```

Obviously, I haven't gotten accustomed to `data.table`, so I'm banging my head against the wall at the moment...

If anybody could provide a `dplyr` solution in addition to `data.table`, I would be thankful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `set` and assign the rows where the value is 0  with the `max` of that column +1.

```
 for(j in c("y", "z")){
    set(df1, i= which(!df1[[j]]), j=j, value= max(df1[[j]])+1)
 }

df1
#   x  y z
#1: 1 16 1
#2: 2 16 1
#3: 4 10 1
#4: 0 15 2
```

NOTE: The `set` method will be very efficient as the overhead of `[.data.table` is avoided

---

Or a less efficient method would be to specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols`, loop through the columns (`lapply(..`), `replace` the value based on the logical index, and assign (`:=`) the output back to the columns.

```
df1[, c('y', 'z') := lapply(.SD, function(x) 
         replace(x, !x, max(x)+1)), .SDcols= y:z]
```

Comment: thanks again for the help! I was trying to use `set` too, but couldn't help myself around its use. I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The dplyr version is pretty simple (I think)

```
> library(dplyr)
# indented for clarity
> mutate(df1, 
    y= ifelse(y>0, y, max(y)+1), 
    z= ifelse(z>0, z, max(z)+1))

  x  y z
1 1 16 1
2 2 16 1
3 4 10 1
4 0 15 2
```

**EDIT**
As noted by David Arenburg in comments this is helpful for the toy example but not for the data mentione dwith 500 columns. He suggests something similar to:

```
df1 %>% mutate_each(funs(ifelse(. > 0, ., max(.) + 1)), -1)
```

where `-1` specifies all but the first column

Comment: Actually No. OP has 500 columns. "The `dplyr` way" would be something like `dt %>% mutate_each(funs(ifelse(. > 0, ., max(.) + 1)), y:z)` or similar.

Comment: OK, that works too. I'll add it to answer with ref to you.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, `ifelse(test, yes, no)` might be useful

Along the lines

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x = c(1,2,4,0), y = c(0,0,10,15), z = c(1,1,1,0))

print(dt)

dt[, y := ifelse(!y, max(y) + 1, y)]

print(dt)
```

Comment: thanks. However, since I have almost 500 columns, it would become difficult to use ifelse for each column. Could `lapply` be used here for an easier `ifelse`?

Comment: @info_seekeR Yes, `lapply` can be used here in the same way as in akrun's post. Because you say you have large data, you might want to consider this post that says `ifelse` can be slow (I'm not sure it applies to your case): http://stackoverflow.com/a/16275201/1191259

Comment: @info_seekeR how to loop over columns is orthogonal to the question what  to do with each column, so as @Frank said, `lapply` could be used in the same way as in @arkun's answer. Wrt being slow or not, you have ot measure. If speed is of an issue, first thing to do would be, IMHO, to compute `max(c)+1` separately, outside of the either `replace` or `ifelse`

Comment: If you already going this rout you could just do `dt[y == 0L, y := max(dt$y) + 1L]` in order to avoid `ifelse` all together (which adds nothing new to `replace` IMO).