# Replacing N/A with other value in data.table returns error

Tags: r, data.table

I want to replace NA with other value for specific column in data.table.
I tried below link but some error shows up.

[How to replace NA values in a table *for selected columns*? data.frame, data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379081/how-to-replace-na-values-in-a-table-for-selected-columns-data-frame-data-tab)

The codes that I use are

```
df<-data.table(aa<-(1:4),ba<-c(NA,1,3,4),ca<-c(NA,"2012-01-02","2012-02-02","2012-03-02"))

df[is.na(get(ca)),(ca):="2012-04-01"]
```

I got the error message: Error in get(c) : object 'NA' not found

But if I use

```
df[is.na(ca),(ca):="2012-04-01"]
```

It returns results that I don't want.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we use the correct column names, it would work, and we don't need `get`.

```
df[is.na(ca), ca:= "2012-04-01"]
df
#  aa ba         ca
#1:  1 NA 2012-04-01
#2:  2  1 2012-01-02
#3:  3  3 2012-02-02
#4:  4  4 2012-03-02
```

Within the `data.table` call, we use `=` instead of `<-`.  In addition, as @Frank mentioned, assigning `(ca)` and `ca` are different as the former could be a `vector` of strings that can be used to create names for new columns.

#### data

```
df<-data.table(aa=(1:4),ba=c(NA,1,3,4),
     ca=c(NA,"2012-01-02","2012-02-02","2012-03-02"))
```

Comment: Maybe worth noting: `(ca) := x` and `ca := x` are very different, since the former (which the OP was doing) actually takes the values of `ca` as names for new columns.

Comment: to OP: `get` expects a `character` constant, so `df[is.na(get("c")), ("c") := "2012-04-01"]` would work (though is unnecessarily complicated in this case). `akrun`'s approach is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. @akrun and @ MichealChirico. I learnt two ways to do that.