# How can I most efficiently set 0 vals to NA in a subset of columns?

Tags: r

I have a book on statistics (using R) showing the following:

```
> pima$diastolic [pima$diastolic = = 0] <- NA
> pima$glucose [pima$glucose == 0] <- NA
> pima$triceps [pima$triceps == 0] <- NA
> pima$insulin [pima$insulin == 0] <- NA
> pima$bmi [pima$bmi == 0] <- NA
```

Is there a way to do it in one line or more efficiently? I see there are functions such as with, apply, subset for doing similar stuff but could not figure out how to put them together...

Sample data (how do I read this in as a dataframe (like pythons stringio):

```
  pregnant glucose diastolic triceps insulin  bmi diabetes age     test
1        6     148        72      35       0 33.6    0.627  50 positive
2        1      85        66      29       0 26.6    0.351  31 negative
3        8     183        64       0       0 23.3    0.672  32 positive
4        1      89        66      23      94 28.1    0.167  21 negative
5        0     137        40      35     168 43.1    2.288  33 positive
6        5     116        74       0       0 25.6    0.201  30 negative
```

Comment: could you provide us with some sample data?

Comment: If you want to replace all `0`s in in a data frame with `NA`, you can easily do it as: `df[df == 0 ] <- NA`

Comment: Or `is.na(df) <-  df == 0`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this:

- Use `lapply()` to use a function for every column
- In the function, test if the column is numeric. If numeric, then replace zeros with NA, else return the original column, unchanged:

Try this:

```
pima[] <- lapply(pima, function(x){ if(is.numeric(x)) x[x==0] <- NA else x})
```

Or for predefined columns

```
cols = c("diastolic", "glucose", "triceps", "insulin", "bmi")
pima[cols] <- lapply(pima[cols], function(x) {x[x==0] <- NA ; x})
```

Or using `is.na<-`

```
is.na(pima[cols]) <- pima[cols] == 0
```

Comment: This will probably return a list instead of a `data.frame`. You probably will need `pima[] <-...`. And `lapply` probably isn't necessary here at all (unless you are trying to avoid matrix conversions).

Comment: @DavidArenburg You're correct about the `pima[] <-`.  I edited my answer, thanks.  You're probably also correct about not needing `lapply()` but life is too short to remember every possible method that you can use directly on a data frame. I know that `lapply()` works for this type of problem, so I tend to use it this way in my own work...

Comment: This is not a subset of the columns though, it is all of them afaics...

Answer (score 0):

Using data.table you can try

```
for (col in c("diastolic","glucose","triceps","insulin", "bmi")) pima[(get(col))==0, (col) := NA]
```

more details here:
[How to replace NA values in a table *for selected columns*? data.frame, data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379081/how-to-replace-na-values-in-a-table-for-selected-columns-data-frame-data-tab)[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379081/how-to-replace-na-values-in-a-table-for-selected-columns-data-frame-data-tab)

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`, you could do:

```
# banal function definition 
zero_to_NA <- function(col) {
    # any code that works here
    # I chose this because it is concise and efficient
    `is.na<-`(col, col==0)
}

# Assuming you want to change 0 to NA only in these 3 columns
pima <- pima %>% 
    mutate_each(funs(zero_to_NA), diastolic, glucose, triceps)
```

Or you could skip the function definition and write directly:

```
pima <- pima %>% 
    mutate_each(funs(`is.na<-`(., .==0)), 
                diastolic, glucose, triceps)
```