# Replace NA with 0 in factor-type column

Tags: r

I have a continuous field (HighBAC) that I am trying to categorize based on whether the BAC falls into a certain range:

BAC >= .16 or < .21 : category 1

BAC >= .09 or < .16 : category 2

```
State       Year    high_bac
Alabama     2016    0.15
Alabama     2015    0.15
Alabama     2011    N
Alabama     2010    N
Arizona     2016    0.15
Arizona     2015    0.15
Idaho       2016    0.2
Idaho       2015    0.2
Idaho       2014    O
Idaho       2013    O
```

But I can't do that until I've replaced the 'N' and 'O' characters with `NA`. Otherwise, the `cut()` function won't work.

```
df_codes$high_bac[df_codes$high_bac=='N'|df_codes$high_bac=='O'] = NA
df_codes$high_bac = as.numeric(df_codes$high_bac)
df_codes$high_bac <- cut(df_codes$high_bac, breaks=c(.09, .16, .22), right=FALSE, labels=c(2:1))
```

Output:

```
State       Year    high_bac
Alabama     2016    2
Alabama     2015    2
Alabama     2011    NA
Alabama     2010    NA
Arizona     2016    2
Arizona     2015    2
Idaho       2016    1
Idaho       2015    1
Idaho       2014    NA
Idaho       2013    NA
```

I would like to then replace the `NA`s with 0s, AFTER I categorize them, because 0 is a special code (that should not be included as a category). But when I use the solution suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379081/how-to-replace-na-values-in-a-table-for-selected-columns-data-frame-data-tab?lq=1), I get the following error:

```
df_codes$high_bac[is.na(df_codes$high_bac)] <- 0
```

> Warning message:
>   In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, is.na(df_codes$high_bac), value = c(1L,  :
>   invalid factor level, NA generated

Does `is.na()` not work with factor-type columns? If that's the case, is there another way I can replace all the `NA`s with 0? Or is there a way to use `cut()` with non-numeric columns?

(Context: I'm categorizing states based on their threshold for super-drunk drivers. States with lower BAC thresholds get more points. But states that have no super-drunk BAC levels ('N' or 'O') get zero points.)

Comment: `cut` gives a `factor` output. Convert the column to `character` class and it would work.  But , it is better to leave it as NA

Comment: I converted it to character form and it worked-- thanks. I agree, better to leave it as NA, but I was requested to change them to zeroes. Thanks for the help, and sorry for the easy question-- I'm new to the R language.

Comment: `df_codes$high_bac <- as.numeric(as.character(df_codes$high_bac)); df_codes$high_bac[is.na(df_codes$high_bac)] <- 0; cut(df_codes$high_bac, breaks=c(0, .09, .16, .22), right=FALSE, labels=c(0,2:1))` would also work

Comment: That's just what I was looking for-- I couldn't figure out the `label` syntax for including 0 as a special code (i.e. without including in the range and accidentally giving it a high point value when it shouldn't have any points at all). Thanks!