# Replace <NA> in a factor column

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, na

I want to replace `<NA>` values in a factors column with a valid value. But I can not find a way. This example is only for demonstration. The original data comes from a foreign csv file I have to deal with.

```
df <- data.frame(a=sample(0:10, size=10, replace=TRUE),
                 b=sample(20:30, size=10, replace=TRUE))
df[df$a==0,'a'] <- NA
df$a <- as.factor(df$a)
```

Could look like this

```
      a  b
1     1 29
2     2 23
3     3 23
4     3 22
5     4 28
6  <NA> 24
7     2 21
8     4 25
9  <NA> 29
10    3 24
```

Now I want to replace the `<NA>` values with a number.

```
df[is.na(df$a), 'a'] <- 88
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = c(88, 88)) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

I think I missed a fundamental R concept about factors. Am I?
I can not understand why it doesn't work. I think `invalid factor level` means that `88` is not a valid level in that factor, right? So I have to tell the factor column that there is another level?

Comment: I don't understand why you have the line of code, df$a <- as.factor(df$a) why do you want that column to be factors?

Comment: @buhtz: if one does not sample a value of `0` in the `data.frame` call will not be able to replicate your problem, maybe better to `set.seed()`.

Comment: @000andy8484 Thanks for that hint. I will pin that to my notes for the next time.

Comment: @user1945827 It is just to imitate my real data (commin from a foreign csv file) and real situation plus providing a minimal example.

Comment: I would suggest that the factor is a red herring.  When you  import the data using the function read.csv() you need to set, stringsAsFactors=F and this will remove any factors in your resulting data.frame.

Comment: @user1945827 Awsome! Thanks.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

**1) addNA** If `fac` is a factor `addNA(fac)` is the same factor but with NA added as a level.  See `?addNA`

To force the NA level to be 88:

```
facna <- addNA(fac)
levels(facna) <- c(levels(fac), 88)
```

giving:

```
> facna
 [1] 1  2  3  3  4  88 2  4  88 3 
Levels: 1 2 3 4 88
```

**1a)**  This can be written in a single line as follows:

```
`levels<-`(addNA(fac), c(levels(fac), 88))
```

**2) factor** It can also be done in one line using the various arguments of `factor` like this:

```
factor(fac, levels = levels(addNA(fac)), labels = c(levels(fac), 88), exclude = NULL)
```

**2a)** or equivalently:

```
factor(fac, levels = c(levels(fac), NA), labels = c(levels(fac), 88), exclude = NULL)
```

**3) ifelse** Another approach is:

```
factor(ifelse(is.na(fac), 88, paste(fac)), levels = c(levels(fac), 88))
```

**4) forcats** The forcats package has a function for this:

```
library(forcats)

fct_na_value_to_level(fac, "88")
## [1] 1  2  3  3  4  88 2  4  88 3 
## Levels: 1 2 3 4 88
```

**Note:** We used the following for input `fac`

```
fac <- structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, NA, 2L, 4L, NA, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"), class = "factor")
```

**Update:** Have improved (1) and added (1a).  Later added (4).

Comment: Hey :) I did 1a for a column in my data.frame. The level appears but if I want to calculate means for specific conditions, let say for all b in the above example that have the level NA I get NaN. I tried `mean(df$b[df$a==NA])` Also str(df) gives me: `Factor w/ 3 levels "1", "2", "3", NA:...` I think what I need is `"1", "2", "3", "NA"`right?

Comment: Option 3) worked for me and I could correctly apply it with a pipe. I tested with and without paste(fac) inside the ifelse statement and both worked fine for me. Any specific reason for why the paste needs to be included?

Comment: So that the factor is rebuilt from scratch.

Answer (score 9):

I had similar issues and I want to add what I consider the most pragmatic (and also tidy) solution:

Convert the column to a `character` column, use `mutate` and a simple `ifelse`-statement to change the `NA` values to what you want the factor level to be (I have chosen "None"), convert it back to a `factor` column:

```
df %>% mutate(
a = as.character(a),
a = ifelse(is.na(a), "None", a),
a = as.factor(a)
)
```

Clean and painless because you do not actually have to dabble with `NA` values when they occur in a `factor` column. You bypass the weirdness and end up with a clean `factor` variable.

Also, in response to the comment made below regarding multiple columns: You can wrap the statements in a function and use `mutate_if` to select all factor variables or, if you know the names of the columns of concern, `mutate_at` to apply that function:

```
replace_factor_na <- function(x){
  x <- as.character(x)
  x <- if_else(is.na(x), "None", x)
  x <- as.factor(x)
}

df <- df %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, replace_factor_na)
```

Comment: it worked and i think this is the best answer tidywise.

Comment: how do you do it with mutate_at. imagine one wants to do it for multiple columns

Comment: Moj´s question was valid, especially for large datasets, so I extended my answer to be more flexible and to fix several columns in one go.

Answer (score 8):

other way to do is:

```
#check levels
levels(df$a)
#[1] "3"  "4"  "7"  "9"  "10"

#add new factor level. i.e 88 in our example
df$a = factor(df$a, levels=c(levels(df$a), 88))

#convert all NA's to 88
df$a[is.na(df$a)] = 88

#check levels again
levels(df$a)
#[1] "3"  "4"  "7"  "9"  "10" "88"
```

Answer (score 6):

My way would be a little bit traditional by using `factor` function:

```
a <- factor(a, 
            exclude = NULL, 
            levels = c(levels(a), NA),
            labels = c(levels(a), "None"))
```

You can replace "None" with appropriate replacement that you want (0L for example)

Comment: I think this is the neatest answer of all, done within just one basic function. This should be upvoted more.

Comment: I'm glad to here that, thanks so much

Answer (score 5):

The basic concept of a factor variable is that it can only take specific values, i.e., the `levels`. A value not in the `levels` is invalid.

You have two possibilities:

If you have a variable that follows this concept, make sure to define all levels when you create it, even those without corresponding values.

Or make the variable a character variable and work with that.

PS: Often these problems result from data import. For instance, what you show there looks like it should be a numeric variable and not a factor variable.

Comment: It is hard to decide where to put the green mark here! ;) Your answer provided me the background info about the basic concept I missed before. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `NA` is not a level of that factor:

```
> levels(df$a)
[1] "2"  "4"  "5"  "9"  "10"
```

You can't change it straight away, but the following will do the trick:

```
df$a <- as.numeric(as.character(df$a))
df[is.na(df$a),1] <- 88
df$a <- as.factor(df$a)
> df$a
 [1] 9  88 3  9  5  9  88 8  3  9 
Levels: 3 5 8 9 88
> levels(df$a)
[1] "3"  "5"  "8"  "9"  "88"
```

Comment: `df$a <- as.numeric(levels(df$a))[df$a]` is a slightly more efficient variant for `as.numeric(as.character())`.