# Having Trouble Replacing NA

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I'm using a data set from kaggle [on bombing operations in WWII](https://www.kaggle.com/usaf/world-war-ii)

I wanted to replace all the NA's in a column with "UKNOWN" but I get this

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, is.na(operations[,"theater.of.operations"]),  :
invalid factor level, NA generated
```

This is how I tried to do it

```
operations[, "theater.of.operations"][is.na(operations[, "theater.of.operations"])] <- "UNKNOWN"
```

How else should I try to do this?

Comment: convert to character

Comment: Try using as.character() to cast your df column to a character first as Sotos mentions

Comment: Thanks I didn't really know what was meant by "convert to character" but @SingleEntity made it more clear, so I used "operations$theater.of.operations <- as.character(operations$theater.of.operations) " and it worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [invalid factor level, NA generated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819956/invalid-factor-level-na-generated)

Comment: The Solution to that question is different to mine

Comment: Glad it worked for you, I shall add an answer to your question to make it official :)

Comment: Another possible dupe: [replace <NA> in a factor column in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126537/replace-na-in-a-factor-column-in-r).

Comment: Yes these are close duplicates, but not exact.  I feel there has to be some understanding that the user may not have enough present knowledge to understand how those questions relate to their question, and that should be acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert `NA` (which is not of string type) to a string such as `"UNKNOWN"` you need to cast your dataframe column to a string as follows.

```
operations$theater.of.operations <- as.character(operations$theater.of.operations)
```

The critical element being the function `as.character()` which casts to your required character variable type.