# Replacing multiple columns with NA Factor Levels with "None"

Tags: r, function, dataframe, na, levels

I'm using the dataset House Prices: Advanced Regression Techniques, which includes multiple factor variables that have NA's among their levels. Consider the columns PoolQL, Alley and MiscFeatures. I want to replace for all these `NA`'s with `None` in one function, but I fail to do so. Tried this so far:

```
MissingLevels <- function(x){
  for(i in names(x)){
  levels <- levels(x[i])
  levels[length(levels) + 1] <- 'None'
  x[i] <- factor(x[i], levels = levels)
  x[i][is.na(x[i])] <- 'None'
  return(x)
  }
}

MissingLevels(df[,c('Alley', 'Fence')])

apply(df[,c('Alley', 'Fence')], 2, MissingLevels)
```

https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways e.g.:

```
x <- data.frame(another = 1:3, Alley = c("A", "B", NA), Fence = c("C", NA, NA))
```

Option 1: using `forcats` package

```
x[,c("Alley", "Fence")] <- lapply(x[,c("Alley", "Fence")], fct_explicit_na, na_level = "None")

  another Alley Fence
1       1     A     C
2       2     B  None
3       3  None  None
```

Option 2:

```
x[,c("Alley", "Fence")] <- lapply(x[,c("Alley", "Fence")], function(x){`levels<-`(addNA(x), c(levels(x), "None"))})
```

PS: The second answer is inspired in @G. Grothendieck post [replace <NA> in a factor column in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126537/replace-na-in-a-factor-column-in-r)

Comment: Sweet! Very concise functions. I like it. For me,this works very neatly: apply(df[,c("Alley", "Fence")], 2, fct_explicit_na, na_level = "None").

Comment: Why use `sapply` or `apply(df, 2...` and coerce the data.frame to a matrix? `lapply` would be more appropriate, when combined with overwriting the original `x`

Comment: I think you are right @thelatemail. lapply preserves the class factor, whereas apply changes the variables to character.

Comment: True @thelatemail. Thanks . Edited.