# Replace NAs in columns with specific variable names

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, na, missing-data

I have a dataframe with 14 columns. 12 of the columns end with the variable name `.T`, and I want to replace NAs with 0 in these columns only. I've tried using `mutate_if()` as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379081/how-to-replace-na-values-in-a-table-for-selected-columns), but I get the error message `Error: No tidyselect variables were registered Call`rlang::last_error()`to see a backtrace`.

My code (with sample data) is as follows:

```
 library(tibble)

 mydf <- tribble(~Var1, ~Var2.a, ~Var3.a,
                 "A", NA, 1,
                 NA, NA, NA,
                 "C", 3, 3,
                 NA, NA, NA)

 newdf <- mydf %>%
   mutate_if(contains(".a"), ~replace_na(., 0))
```

> Error: No tidyselect variables were registered
>        Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

I'd like to use `dplyr` if possible.

Comment: **Self promotion**: `mde::recode_na_as(mydf,0,subset_df=T,tidy=T,pattern_type="ends_with",pattern=".a")`

Answer (score 3):

You should use `mutate_at`, also include the column name in `vars()`

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% mutate_at(vars(contains(".a")), replace_na, 0)

#  Var1  Var2.a Var3.a
#  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 A          0      1
#2 NA         0      0
#3 C          3      3
#4 NA         0      0
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to use `mutate_at`:

```
newdf <- mydf %>%
   mutate_at(vars(matches("\\.a")), ~replace_na(., 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

In base R you may use `grep`.

```
r <- grep("\\.a", names(mydf))
mydf[r][is.na(mydf[r])] <- 0

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   Var1  Var2.a Var3.a
#   <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 A          0      1
# 2 NA         0      0
# 3 C          3      3
# 4 NA         0      0
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use is.na. For example:

```
df$x[is.na(df$x] <- 0
```

You can also do this for multiple columns at once using df[,2:6] (e.g. columns 2 through 6)