# Converting a factor with 2 levels to binary values 0/1 in R

Tags: r, binary, r-factor

I have a variable, called `gender`, with binary categorical values "female"/"male". I want to change its type to integers 0/1 so that I can use it in a regression analysis. i.e I want values "female" and "male" to be mapped to 1 and 0.

```
> str(gender)
gender : Factor w/ 2 levels "female","male":  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 ...
> gender[1]
[1] female
```

I would like to convert gender variable type so that I get int value 1 when I query an element, i.e.

```
> gender[1]
[1] 1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! maybe it should be better show what you have tried.

Comment: what about `gender <- ifelse(gender=="female",1,0)`?

Answer (score 15):

As an addition to @Dason's answer, note that...

```
test <- c("male","female")

as.factor(test)
#[1] male   female
#Levels: female male
```

...will return `female` as the reference group (1) and `male` as the comparison group (2),

To spin it the other way, you would need to do...

```
factor(test,levels=c("male","female"))
#[1] male   female
#Levels: male female
```

As @marius notes, using `contrasts` will show you how it will work in the regression model:

```
contrasts(as.factor(test))
#       male
#female    0
#male      1

contrasts(factor(test,levels=c("male","female")))
#       female
#male        0
#female      1
```

Comment: Or, to see even more explicitly how the levels will be treated in a regression model, `contrasts(factor(test))`

Answer (score 14):

Convert to a factor and let R take care of the rest.  You should never have to take care of explicitly creating dummy variables when using R.

Comment: +1 far better to address the real issue, not the exact problem!

Comment: @Dason, what about if you wanted to include gender in a correlation matrix? This will not work if gender is a factor.

Answer (score 7):

If you're doing this for real, you should absolutely follow @Dason's advice. I'm going to assume that you're teaching a class and want to demonstrate indicator variables (with thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5048638/1465387)):

```
dat <- data.frame(gender=sample(c("male", "female"), 10, replace=TRUE))

model.matrix(~gender, data=dat)

   (Intercept) gendermale
1            1          1
2            1          0
3            1          1
4            1          0
5            1          1
6            1          1
7            1          1
8            1          0
9            1          0
10           1          1
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$gender
[1] "contr.treatment"
```

If you don't want the intercept, use `model.matrix(~gender -1 , data=dat)` instead.