# Is there any way to fit a `glm()` so that all levels are included (i.e. no reference level)?

Tags: r, glm, levels

Consider the code:

```
x <- read.table("http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/datasets/cuse.dat",
                header=TRUE)[,1:2]

fit <- glm(education ~ age, family="binomial", data=x)

summary(fit)
```

Where age has 4 levels: "<25"   "25-29" "30-39" "40-49"

The results are:

[image]

So by default, one of the levels is used as a reference level. Is there a way to have glm output coefficients for all 4 levels + the intercept (i.e. have no reference level)? Software packages like SAS do this by default, so I was wondering if there was any option for this.

Thanks!

Comment: My understanding is that the coefficient for the reference level is just 0.

Comment: You are looking for something called `effect coding`. See [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52132/how-to-do-regression-with-effect-coding-instead-of-dummy-coding-in-r)

Comment: does SAS really output intercept *and* all four levels?  It doesn't really make sense to *parameterize* a model with N+1 parameters when there are only N levels, but you can output *predictions* of the model for all four levels with e.g. the `lsmeans` package.  It might be helpful to show the SAS output for the corresponding model, illustrating what you want.

Answer (score 3):

See `?formula`, specifically, the meaning of including `+ 0` in your model specification...

```
# Sample data - explanatory variable (continuous)
x <- runif( 100 )
# explanatory data, factor with 3 levels
f <- as.factor( sample( 3 , 100 , TRUE ) )
# outcome data
y <- runif( 100 ) + rnorm(100) + rnorm( 100 , mean = c(1,3,6) )

# model without intercept
summary( glm( y ~ x + f + 0 ) )
#Call:
#glm(formula = y ~ x + f + 0)

#Deviance Residuals: 
#    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
#-5.7316  -1.8923   0.0195   1.8918   5.9520  

#Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#x    0.3216     0.9772   0.329    0.743    
#f1   3.4493     0.6823   5.055 2.06e-06 ***
#f2   3.6349     0.6959   5.223 1.02e-06 ***
#f3   3.1962     0.6598   4.844 4.87e-06 ***
```

Comment: So what would the intercept be if you include all the levels? Look at the parameter differences when running `+0` and `+1` (i.e. with intercept)...

Comment: I don't think I've seen "+0" used for this, I think the usual method is "-1".

Comment: @Spacedman Again, I refer you to `?formula`! *A model with no intercept can be also specified as `y ~ x + 0` or `y ~ 0 + x`.* :-)

Comment: Yes, I wasn't questioning its correctness, just its frequency! FWIW `x-0` is different to `x+0` which disagrees with the mathematician in me, and any other constant generates an error!

Comment: @Spacedman ok, ok! I prefer `+ 0` myself, because I think of it as `+ 0*b0` i.e. the model must run through the origin so account for all other parameters if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the `model.matrix` function to convert the factors in the age variable to binary variables.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048638/automatically-expanding-an-r-factor-into-a-collection-of-1-0-indicator-variables) answer.

EDIT:
Here is an example:

```
x <- read.table("http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/datasets/cuse.dat",
                header=TRUE)[,1:2]
binary_variables <- model.matrix(~ x$age -1, x)
fit <- glm(x$education ~ binary_variables, family="binomial")
summary(fit)
```

Comment: `glm` does this anyway when using factor variables. I don't see how this helps. Just include `-1` or `+0` in the model spec and this will be taken care of automagically.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I had no idea glm did that. Please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: it can still be useful to know how to do this in some contexts (e.g. sometimes you want to drop derived (input) variables from the model in a way that is (AFAIK) impossible to specify via a formula ...

Comment: @theWanderer4865 Sorry that wasn't meant to come across as rude! I just think you should be aware it's unnecessary for convenience, but Ben is absolutely right and sometimes it is good to know how the model is working 'under the hood' as it were so you understand what it *means*. So in that context it *is* useful.

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon, I think you are wrong, becasue your suggestion doesn't seem to include the intercept (which the OP wants), while this solution includes the intercept too

Comment: @DavidArenburg The intercept in that case is `0` to the best approximation that R can muster (5e-16!!!) due to bad dataset (which is mentioned in the summary). The effect of `-1` or `+0` is to force the line through the origin. Run `model.matrix` with and without `-1` and look at `binary_variables`.

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon, you are right, I didn't notice that it's 0, but would it be always 0, i.e., for a better data set?

Comment: AFAIK, due to the effect of what `-1` is actually doing it should *better* converge on 0 with more data as that is in effect what it is *supposed* to be doing. @BenBolker knows for sure though.

Comment: You are, right, I didn't know that `-1` syntax takes out the intercept. Actually I wasn't attacking you, but aksing questions out of interest. I never used the `model.matrix` function before so just was qurious

Comment: It surprises me a little that `lm` doesn't detect the overspecified model in this case.  The answer's actually arbitrary; it's like fitting a model `Y=a0+a1+b*x` -- any linear combination of `a0` and `a1` that add up to the true intercept will be equally good fits.

Comment: I'm now a little sorry I upvoted (since now that I look more closely I see that the model is overfitted): I would prefer that you use `+0` or `-1` in your `lm` call to suppress the intercept, since otherwise the results are very likely to be misleading. I don't seem to be able to retract my upvote without downvoting ...