# Different types of categorical variables and how to make R use them in PCA

Tags: r, pca

I am starting to use R, and learning about the PCA analysis too, but my problem here relates to categorical variables.

I have three main types of categorical variables in my data set.

Type one: Presence/absence of a trait, and I know that I can transform that into 1/0 in the table and no worries.

Type two: Frequency or abundance of a trait, that I assume R will understand if I transform something that is absent/less abundant/abundant into 0/1/2, for example.

Type three: The problematic one. This is truly categorical, functioning as a label. The name of the variable is "cambial variant", and the possibilites are: absent/lobed/compound/fissured/corded and so on...
These are different types of cambial variants, and those different types can be found in different species of plants.

First I assumed that it would be ok to simply use different numbers for these different types (ex: absent=0, lobed=1, compound=2, and so on). So I performed the **prcomp** like that, and the results were exactly what I expected. But then I realized I made a mistake by using different numbers for things that are not related at all, right? The program understands that 3 is bigger than 2, and that is somehow wrong, because the "fissured type" and the "compound type" are not levels of intensity (abundance, frequency, whatever) of the same thing. They are different types of a same structure, but one does not transform into the other, they are not related in that type of way.

So, in sum, I want to know how I could transform this variables that are more like labels into something that the function **prcomp** can understand and use. Or, if that is not an option, if there is another function in R that can do a PCA with these categorical variables that can`t be modified into numbers.

Thanks you all, and I am sorry if my question is way too dumb, I am really just a beginner here!

Comment: You might want to consider [Automatically expanding an R factor into a collection of 1/0 indicator variables for every factor level](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5048638/6455166).

Comment: The main objective of doing a PCA is mainly to get uncorrelated Principle components. I can understand that the diversity of people who use R makes it extremely difficult at times to understand the use case and provide a solution. I did not understand why are you trying to get from a PCA here? If you could elaborate a bit more on your objective, more people would be able to help you out. Welcome to the community! :)