# R: is there something like dmatrices ( from python) in R for categorical values?

Tags: r, function, regression, categorical-data

In python you can use the dmatrices function from the patsy module when using categorical values for regressions to create 0 and 1 matrices for the categorical values.

Is there a library/function in R that performs the same function?

Comment: `?model.matrix`.  This is probably a duplicate ...

Comment: e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048638/automatically-expanding-an-r-factor-into-a-collection-of-1-0-indicator-variables/5048726#5048726

Comment: Also worth pointing out that in most regression modelling functions in R you don't actually have to do this, since factors are automatically treated like this based on their `contrasts` attribute.

Comment: oh wow - so in R, I can just use the categorical columns in my dataframe as the coefficients and it will automatically use 0/1 matrices in my regression model?

Comment: that's right ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have this data frame where columns x and y are numeric and column f is a factor.  Then we can run the regression like this and `lm` will convert the formula to an appropriate model matrix including 0/1 columns and then run the regression on that:

```
# test data
set.seed(123)
DF <- transform(data.frame(f = gl(3, 5, labels = letters[1:3]), x = 1:15),
         y = rnorm(15, 1:15))

# run regression
fo <- y ~ x + f
lm(fo, DF)
```

The model matrix is computed in doing the above so there is no need to explicitly compute it but if you want to anyways try this:

```
# view model matrix
model.matrix(fo, DF)
```

Comment: That's great! Thank you - exactly what I needed