# one hot encoding function

Tags: r, one-hot-encoding

I need to create a function that takes two integer numbers `x` and `N`, where `N > x` and returns a vector of dimension `N` with all zeros with the exception of component `x`, in which it has a `1`.

I managed to do it in the following way,

```
Function=function(x,N){
  vec=rep(0,N)
  r=as.integer(x)
  vec[r]=1
  return(vec)
}
```

but it is incredibly slow when I need to iterate the process and apply it to a large number of realizations. On the other hand, a friend of mine is able to do the same thing with a single function of python (I think "OneHotEncoder") and it's super fast.

I was wondering if there are functions in R that are suited for this purpose.

Comment: The problem may lie in the way how you apply this function to larger cases, and less the function itself.

Comment: without defining a custom function, you can do
`library(magrittr); integer(N) %>% \`[<-\`(x, 1L)`

Comment: Rather than writing your own one-hot encoder, you could use one of the already-available optimized methods, like `model.matrix` (or `Matrix::sparse.model.matrix`, if your data is really large). If you search the R tag for "one hot encoding" or "dummy variables", you will find many examples.

Comment: Related posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048638/automatically-expanding-an-r-factor-into-a-collection-of-1-0-indicator-variables and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952706/generate-a-dummy-variable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Along the lines of what @Axeman said, you should think of whether you could find the one-hot-encoding in a vectorized way, i.e., something like that

```
set.seed(1234)
x = sample.int(5, size=10, replace=TRUE)
x
#  [1] 1 4 4 4 5 4 1 2 4 3

nC = max(x) #could be also larger (user-defined)
nR = length(x)
matrix(`[<-`(integer(nR * nC),(seq.int(nR) - 1) * nC + x, 1),
       nR, nC, byrow=TRUE)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#  [1,]    1    0    0    0    0
#  [2,]    0    0    0    1    0
#  [3,]    0    0    0    1    0
#  [4,]    0    0    0    1    0
#  [5,]    0    0    0    0    1
#  [6,]    0    0    0    1    0
#  [7,]    1    0    0    0    0
#  [8,]    0    1    0    0    0
#  [9,]    0    0    0    1    0
# [10,]    0    0    1    0    0
```

Compare `model.matrix` approach to approach given above:

```
#longer input vector
x = sample.int(5, size=1e4, replace=TRUE)

oneHotMtx = function(x) {
  nC = max(x) #could be also larger (user-defined)
  nR = length(x)
  matrix(`[<-`(integer(nR * nC),(seq.int(nR) - 1) * nC + x, 1),
         nR, nC, byrow=TRUE)
}

oneHotMdl = function(x) {
  xf = factor(x)
  model.matrix(~xf+0)
}

oneHotMdl2=function(x) {
  #version without factor conversion
  model.matrix(~x+0)
}

xf = factor(x)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(oneHotMtx(x),
               oneHotMdl(x),
               oneHotMdl2(xf), times=1e3)

#Unit: microseconds
#          expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq        max neval cld
#  oneHotMtx(x)  386.621  412.510  678.2977  416.4625  435.382   5394.265  1000 a  
#  oneHotMdl(x) 7363.481 7528.230 8823.8435 7629.8850 7851.019 261808.302  1000   c
#oneHotMdl2(xf) 4253.366 4377.784 5059.0979 4471.5315 4638.637 257106.400  1000  b
```

Comment: But why use this method to one-hot encode one variable at a time instead of using `model.matrix` to do them all at once? No doubt this is an improvement on OP's code, but why stop here?

Comment: Nice, though I do think it's not really fair to include the factor conversion in the model matrix runtime, I think the more common use case would be starting with factors.

Comment: Thank you @Gregor, I think that you got precisely where the problem was.  Until now I was using a for loop to apply the function to every components of large vectors. "model.matrix" seems to be what I was looking for. I'll study how it works right now.

Comment: @Gregor Good point - added another version without factor conversion.

Comment: @3sm1r just make sure any columns you want to one-hot encode are factors, then `mm = model.matrix(response ~ . + 0, data = your_data_frame)`.

Comment: @cryo111 
I had to think about it, but now I get your point: you are saying that encoding with a vector operation is way faster than solving the problem considering the components one by one. I'll surely give it a try. Thanks

Comment: EDIT @cryo111
The speed has increased by orders of magnitude with your method. Thanks again.

Comment: @3sm1r Gregor's solution comes with some advantages, such as that it can be easily applied to multiple factors at once (see his comment above). However, `model.matrix` also seems to have some overhead (maybe `NA` handling or similar...) that makes it a bit slower than the "pure" matrix-based approach. What works better really depends on your data...

Comment: @cryo111 my data are quite simple: I have vectors with 64 components each of which can have values from 0 to 12 (a chessboard). I want to transform these vectors in new vectors with 13*64=832 components with 0 or 1 as possible values each. Both your methods seem to work well for this purpose.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
one_hot_encoder <- function(x, N) {
  vec <- integer(N)
  vec[x] <- 1L
  return(vec)
}
```

Comment: Using 1L instead of 1 would avoid the forced conversion of `vec` from integer to numeric.

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you.

Answer (score 1):

A litle bit more detaild variant of the @cryo111 answer:

```
one_hot_vec <- function(x) {
    nc <- max(x)
    nr <- length(x)
    m <- integer(nr * nc)
    i <- (seq_len(nr) - 1) * nc + x
    m[i] <- 1L
    matrix(m, nrow = nr, ncol = nc, byrow = TRUE)
}
```