# Logistic regression in R with bootstrapping constant ERROR

Tags: r, statistics, logistic-regression, statistics-bootstrap

I am working on an exercise for a statistics online course. I need to make a logistic multivariate regresssion in R using a dataset which contains 19 variables of which one is a predictor binary variable. I want to apply the bootstrap method and stepwise backward elimination to make a model that contains fewer variables and only variables that appear in at least 70% of the bootstrap models.

My code is here:

```
# Step 1: Multiple imputation using chained equations (MICE)
library(mice)
library(mitools)

Rubin_imp <- mice(Final_model_above_5, m = 40)  # Generate 40 imputed datasets

# Combine the imputed datasets using Rubin's rules
imputed_data <- complete(Rubin_imp, "long", include = TRUE)

# Step 2: Bootstrap linear regression model with sandwich variance estimator
library(boot)
library(car)

# Set the seed for reproducibility
set.seed(12345)

# Define the formula for the regression model
formula <- eaten_within_3_months ~ .

# Create a variable occurrence counter
variable_counts <- rep(0, length(names(Final_model_above_5)))

# Define a function to perform the bootstrap regression, count variable occurrences, and track iteration number
bootstrap_regression <- function(data, indices) {
  # Get the bootstrap sample
  bootstrap_sample <- data[indices, ]
  
  # Fit the regression model using backward selection
  model <- stepAIC(glm(formula, data = bootstrap_sample, family = "binomial"), 
                   direction = "backward", 
                   scope = list(lower = ~1, upper = ~.))
  
  # Count the occurrences of variables selected in the model
  selected_variables <- names(coef(model))
  variable_counts[selected_variables] <- variable_counts[selected_variables] + 1
  
  # Return the model coefficients
  return(coef(model))
}

# Perform bootstrap sampling and regression
boot_samples <- boot(imputed_data, bootstrap_regression, R = 10)

# Extract the model coefficients from the boot_samples object
coefficients_list <- boot_samples$t

# Print the results and variable occurrences
print(coefficients_list)
cat("\n")

# Step 3: Retain variables that appeared at least 70% of the time
n_boot <- 10  # Number of bootstrap samples
threshold <- n_boot * 0.7  # Minimum occurrence threshold (70% of the bootstraps)

# Get the variable names that appeared at least threshold times
selected_variables <- names(variable_counts[variable_counts >= threshold])

# Print the selected variables
cat("Selected Variables:", selected_variables, "\n")
```

BUT I keep getting an error saying:

```
Error in t.star[r, ] <- res[[r]] : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I would be grateful is anyone had a solution/ an easier way of doing this.

Comment: I don't know the exact source of your problem, but `variable_counts` is only being updated within the `bootstrap_regression` function so its value is going to be unaffected outside of that function. So it will always be zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this question can be a bit daunting if the problem is not reproducible. See this reference for information on that: [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Regarding the question, the error message seems similar to one discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53023472/how-to-resolve-number-of-items-to-replace-is-not-a-multiple-of-replacement-leng), and it could have something to do with first having to expand factor levels using `model.matrix()`.